Why IntelliJ IDEA treats subfolder of my project as root folder?
Let's say I want to create new project in IntelliJ IDEA. I click File->New->Project, fill out all fields and get fresh project with structure like this:
.
└── my-project/
    ├── .git
    ├── .idea
    ├── .mvn
    ├── src
    ├── target
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── mvnw
    └── pom.xml

I want to dockerize my application and create volume between my project and filesystem inside docker container. Since I:

Want to be able to access Dockerfile from IDE file tree view
Don't want Dockerfile to be in the volume

I decide to create directory app and move all Java/Maven files needed to launch project inside.
.
└── my-project/
    ├── .git
    ├── .idea
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── app/
    │   ├── .mvn
    │   ├── src
    │   ├── target
    │   ├── mvnw
    │   └── pom.xml
    ├── docker/
    │   └── app/
    │       └── Dockerfile
    └── compose.yaml

Everything works fine until by some reason I need to reload Maven project (Right click on pom.xml -> Maven -> Reload project). Then IDE tree view starts to show only files located in my-project/app directory, like this directory is a root of project
.
└── app/
    ├── .mvn
    ├── src
    ├── target
    ├── mvnw
    └── pom.xml

Even if I'm trying to explicitly open my-project directory as a project (File -> Open -> Select "my-project" directory) IDE opens directory my-project/app, not my-project.

Why IDEA opens my-project/app directory instead of my-project? I assume IDEA treats directory where pom.xml located as root of project. Is it correct?
How I can move pom.xml into subdirectory without breaking IDE tree file view?


In intellij you will find a option Invalidate Cache from File tab. As intellij cache your imported project that's why an issue can occurred.
Now note the point, if you load pom file in intellij it automatically import all other file on pom's same directory level.
As you want to load my-project directory. Try to open my-project as project. Hope it will work.
And one more thing, if you want to build the project with mvn clean install you need to go inside app directory and then need to build
